# How to get the entire row using max() using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to calculate the SUM of values from MySQL and was able to get the highest `$total` value.

My SQL Table is

```
USER 1
crit_1 = 75
crit_2 = 75
USER 2
crit_1 = 100
crit_2 = 100
```

My PHP goes like this:

```
$crit_1 = $row["crit_1"];
$crit_2 = $row["crit_2"];
$sum = ($crit_1 + $crit_2);
$total = number_format ($sum / 2, 2, '.',' ');
$totals[] = $total;
$value = max($totals);
```

and here is my HTML

```
<th><strong>Score from Crit_1</strong></th>
<th><strong>Score from Crit_2</strong></th>
<th><strong>TOTAL SCORE OF crit_1 and crit_2</strong></th>

<td align="center"><?php echo $crit_1; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $crit_2; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $total; ?></td>
```

and echoed

```
<?php echo $value; ?>
```

This echoes the Number only. What I wanted to do is how can I get the entire row of scores(from crit_1 to total) with the highest value.

Comment: horrible db structure normalize it to make tour life a million times easier

Answer (score 0):

The reason `$value = max($totals);` is echoing the same value is that in your code example you are only assigning 1 value to the $totals array.

```
$totals = array();
$totals[] =$row['crit1'];
$totals[] = $row['crit2'];
$value = max($totals);
```

should give you the max value in the totals array. Then you need to do something with it...

Not sure why you're dividing by 2? Average? `$total = number_format ($sum / 2, 2, '.',' ');` ???

Refer to the docs for max()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

I would also recommend looking at MySQL SUM and GROUPBY functions
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

below sql will give you only the row with highest total:

```
SELECT (u.crit_1 + u.crit_2) / 2 AS total, max((u.crit_1 + crit_2) / 2), u.* FROM users AS u;
```

but if you want to fetch all rows with totals you can do following:

```
SELECT (u.crit_1 + u.crit_2) / 2 AS total, u.* FROM users AS u
```

But you won't be able to get max here. But in your sample code you have showed all data in a table and max value in somewhere else. So in same way you can print all data in a table by looping through and at that time you can check for the maximum total.

```
$value = -1;        // outside of your loop
$value = max($value, $total);   //inside your loop
```

Note: change `users` with you actual table name.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a your db structure like

```
user_id , crit_1, crit_2 in which user_id is unique field, or whatever you have as unique field for each user.
```

then add that field in your $max_total array like

```
    <?php
    $max_total = array();
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die ("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
    $result =  mysqli_query($conn, "select * from reg")or die("error");
    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr><th><strong>Score from Crit_1</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Score from Crit_2</strong></th>
    <th><strong>TOTAL SCORE OF crit_1 and crit_2</strong></th></tr>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $max_total[$row['user_id']] = $row['crit_1'] + $row['crit_2'];
        echo '<tr><td align="center">'.$row['crit_1'].'</td><td align="center">'.$row['crit_2'].'</td><td align="center">'.($row['crit_1'] + $row['crit_2']).'</td></tr>';
        }
    echo '</table>';
   // echo(max($max_total));

$new = array_flip($max_total);
echo $id = $new[max($max_total)];
```

this `$id` is your `unique field` just use thus and run a query with `where` `condition` in this `query` and `fetch` desired row

Please read about `array_filp` from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Answer (score 0):

mysql> SELECT * , ( crit_1 + crit_2 ) AS total FROM test order by total  desc limit 1;
+--------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| userid | crit_1 | crit_2 | total | total |
+--------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
|      2 |    100 |    100 |     0 |   200 |
+--------+--------+--------+-------+-------+

+--------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| userid | crit_1 | crit_2 | total | total |
+--------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
|      1 |     75 |     75 |     0 |   150 |
|      2 |    100 |    100 |     0 |   200 |
+--------+--------+--------+-------+-------+